# In Finder, how dynamically change folder icon's color when said folder contains .git folder?

Tags: macos, finder, applescript, automation, javascript-automation

Looking for an automated way, in macOS Finder, to change a folder icon from its default blue to green, based on whether or not it contains a `.git` repository.

Can this be scripted or automated with a finder extension or some other tool?

Comment: What do you mean by change the folder icon's colour

Answer (score 1):

Use Hazel, from [Noodlesoft](https://www.noodlesoft.com/).  Read [About Folders & Rules](https://www.noodlesoft.com/manual/hazel/hazel-basics/about-folders-rules/).

Comment: Thanks Marc, Hazel is interesting! Although I’m still hoping for guidance towards a solution using only AppleScript or JavaScript for Automation.

Comment: So "a finder extension or some other tool" was not accurate, it has to be first-party?  Probably figure out something with a Folder Action, but it wouldn't be dynamic.

Comment: My original question was edited... "Finder extension or some other tool" and some extra tags were added to it by an editor, and is now causing confusion.